# Make Firefox (Win7) "x" buttons red

Tags: firefox

FF3 on Win7 has red exes. That is, where in XP the "Stop", "Close Tab", and other "x" buttons were red, in Win7 they are blue.

I prefer the red. How do i change it back?

Comment: I've FF 11 and it has red button by default.

Comment: @avirk Huh? The "close program" button is red, but not "close **tab**". The tab closing `x` is a shade of grey, and indents when hovered over. No red. The stop/cancel button is also a shade of grey, though it does fill in with a not-so-obvious red when hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is install a [theme](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/).

---

#### Firefox 4+

Specifically, [this](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-3-theme-for-firefox/) looks like a good one.

Description:

> As some people think the default Firefox 4 theme is too 'washed out', this theme brings back the colorful look of the default Firefox 3 theme, in Firefox 4 (or later)! This theme is based around the Windows ('winstripe') version of the Firefox 3 theme, as seen outside of Windows Vista/7's 'Aero' mode.

Also, the developer says:

> Once the theme is installed, you need to right-click the toolbar and click 'customize'. Then you can drag icons into place, show icons and text, and disable 'small icons' if you wish.

---

#### Firefox 3

The default theme *should* be what you wanted. If, for whatever reason, it's not, [here](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stratam/)'s an alternative theme. Not perfect, but close.

> Restores icon colours from the default XP theme to the Aero theme, removing much of the blue, while keeping the style of the Aero icons. This is for those people who like the look of the default Aero theme, but want a little less blue without completely reverting to the XP theme.

Comment: Hmm, the theme is not available in FF3. Maybe i need to edit my current theme?

Comment: Maybe you should stop using Firefox 3 in Windows 7? ;) Unless an extension needs that, there's no reason not to upgrade. "Look and feel" can be customised through a variety of extensions, such as re-enabling the menu bar, and there's a built in option to move the tab bar back to where it was in FF3. Aside from look and feel, there's been a whole lot of performance, security and compatibility (HTML5) updates. Just about the only downside is old FF3 extensions that were never updated to work in newer versions.

Comment: Stop using FF3? That gets a BIG red "X". :) I am unlikely to use Chrome...i mean FF4+. Though, i am checking out Safari as a possible replacement.

Comment: Then you probably will have to go the route of making your own theme. There's FF3 themes for FF4+, there's Aero and FF4+ themes for WinXP and/or FF3, but I don't think there's FF3 themes for FF3 on Win7... Actually, could you provide a screenshot? I thought the colours should be the same as FF3 on WinXP, since those are browser features, not OS features.

Comment: Sure [Win7](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/4052/94086531.jpg)
[XP](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/1149/15815083.jpg)

Comment: I just realised I was searching for themes compatible with Firefox 11, since that's the version I was using... silly me. Changing the search options yields http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stratam/ I just realised in that theme's screenshots, the default theme he has is what you want.. so perhaps see if you have any other theme active, or maybe even make a new Firefox profile/reinstall and check there?

Comment: Excellent. That theme gives me a red x. But it also made my reload button green. Now i need to learn to edit the theme. Please make your post a reply, so i can mark it as answer.

Comment: If you rename it to a zip file and extract it, you can edit the images. Specifically, open `\chrome\browser\Toolbar.png` and `\chrome\browser\Toolbar-small.png`. Edit them *carefully*; use some program probably more advanced than paint to apply a gradient to the reload button or replace it (pixel-perfect) with a sample from elsewhere. Or look for the same file in your profile/Firefox install directory, and basically combine them by mixing parts. Then rename back and load in Firefox. If you need more details, I'm sure there's some guide somewhere.

Comment: BTW, current toolbar-small is in: chrome://browser/skin/Toolbar-small.png

Comment: OK, took me a moment, i went to XP, downloaded chrome://browser/skin/Toolbar-small.png, and replaced the strata m file with the one from XP. works perfectly, thanx!